# Looking for a jq filter to exclude nested objects based on the value of a nested property

Tags: filter, nested, key, jq

Given this input:

```
{
  "10000703": {
    "show_id": 1641788,
  },
  "10000838": {
    "show_id": 1517903,
  },
  "10001325": {
    "show_id": 1641788,
  },
}
```

I'm looking for a filter to say "return all objects where `show_id` does not equal `1641788`"

The expected output would be:

```
{
  "10000838": {
    "show_id": 1517903,
  },
}
```

Haven't been able to exclude nested objects :(

Comment: Q: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried a ton of things involving `walk/1` and `del()`, but `with_entries/1` is what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good example of the convenience of `with_entries/1` and of the brevity that's possible with jq:

```
with_entries( select(.value.show_id != 1641788 ))
```

`with_entries/1` converts an object into an explicit .key/.value representation.  Please see the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for details.

Alternatively and with even greater brevity, one can in this case also use `del/1`:

```
del( .[] | select( .show_id == 1641788 ) )
```